# C++ Decrease value every time string passes

Tags: c++

I'm struggling to find a way to decrease the value in a string every time the string is shown.

Using the code below, consider that the 1st line of the text file is `some text #N`. `#N` should be replaced by a number decreasing from 18 to 1. When it reaches 0 it should go back to 18.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

void find_and_replace(string & source, string const & find, string const & replace)
{
    for (string::size_type i = 0; (i = source.find(find, i)) != string::npos;) {
        source.replace(i, find.length(), replace);
        i += replace.length();
    }
}

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    std::ifstream fileIn("Answers.txt", std::ios::in | std::ios::binary);
    string question;
    string line;

    if (!fileIn) {
        cout << "Cannot open input file!" << endl;
        return 1;
    }

    while (getline(fileIn, line)) {
        if (line == "The answer can be found in a secret place in the woods.") {
            fileIn.clear();
            fileIn.seekg(0, ios::beg);
        }
        cout << "Ask a question followed by the Enter key. Or type 'exit' to Exit program.\n";
        getline(cin, question);
        system("CLS");
        find_and_replace(line, "#N", "18");

        if (question == "") {
            cout << "Your input cannot be blank. Please try again.\n\n";
        }

        else if (question == "exit")
            exit(0);

        else {
            cout << "Q: " + question
                 << "\nA: " + line + "\n\n";
        }
    }
}
```

This code only changes `#N` to `18`, nothing more.

Please help guys.

Comment: [Rubber Ducky](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) wants to know why you are using a string for this.

Comment: I haven't a clue what else to use for replacing the 2 charcters. Any solution for this?

Comment: `"18"` is hard coded. There is nothing decrementing, so 'decreasing from 18 to 1' is not happening.

Comment: Use an `int` to keep track of the number. Convert the `int` to a string when needed. Write the converted string.

Comment: Sure I know that. I just posted my code that I'm using, seeking a solution nowhere to be found on google. I've spent my whole day looking for a solution or some snippet of code I could use. 
Is there a way to do math in a string for the decrementing 18 then placing that string as the text to be replaced?

Comment: There are no standard functions to do math on strings. You would have to write this yourself. [However there is a `to_string` function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string) that does pretty much what it sound like.

Comment: ***I've spent my whole day looking for a solution or some snippet of code I could use.*** Then your teacher did his / her homework. Homework is for you to use your mind to come up with a solution so that you can learn and be an effective programmer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have hardcoded the value to 18, and you don't have any code which decrements the number.

Try these changes

put this at the start of main

```
int tempVar=18;
char buffer[100];
```

and replace

```
find_and_replace(line, "#N", "18");
```

with

```
sprintf(buffer,"%d",tempVar--)
if(tempVar<0)
    tempVar=18;
find_and_replace(line, "#N", buffer);
```

https://www.programiz.com/cpp-programming/library-function/cstdio/sprintf

Comment: Thanx will try and give you an update on that sprintf.

Comment: Recommend adding the C++ alternatives since this question isn't tagged with the C programming language.

Comment: I did the sprintf. Working correctly, except that the next time I see the text containing "#N" it replaces it with 10. My program reads a file and prints only one line at a time. It goes in a loop through the lines of text.

Comment: So on the first question it printed 18, but on the second question it printed 10?
Are there many lines in your file with #N in it?

Comment: Oh, now I get it. Your file has multiple lines in it, and tempvar is reduces every time the while loop is iterated, regardless of whether your code found #N or not.

You need to address this first.

Comment: So only when the line of text containing "#N" in the file is going to show on the screen, it should replace "#N" with the number 18 decremented down to 0.

Comment: Could try using an if statement, that when it finds "#N" it should decrement? [EDIT] not working...

Comment: That's 1 part.
The other part is confirming whether the user asks a question or now.

So your find and replace function should be called in the else section.
and you need to check if the line you are passing to find and replace has #N or not.

Comment: What did you use to check if the "#N" is present inside the line or not?
I would have gone for

    if(line.find("#N",0)!=0){
        find_and_replace(line, "#N", "18");
    }

Comment: I'll try that. But what I think my problem is, is that everytime the loop goes to show the next line of text the whole text file is loaded into memory, instead of just the line. So using an if statement before it replaces the "#N" is useless beacuase there's the find_and_replace.

Comment: Small edit, it should be if(line.find("#N",0)>=0){ find_and_replace(line, "#N", "18"); }

Comment: Also I read your full code just now, and it feels like it was written by a  novice.
With the initial impression however I felt the code could have been written by a seasoned programmer. So you are definitely sticking to all the rules.

Comment: Thanx for that compliment I guess. Its a study project, its the introduction to c++. So yeah I'm a novice who actually learned vb.net all by myself.

Comment: I'll have to rearrange my ifs a bit. I'll give you an update and post my code if it works.

Comment: It still decrements even when not displaying that certain line which contains "#N". What to do?

Comment: Thanx for your help btw. I'm gonna be submitting it as is. I still have 3 more projects to cover before the 28th. I have voted yours as the best answer. Unless you come up with something better.

Comment: Hi,
Sorry about not replying afterwards. I fell asleep.

All the best with your submissions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like:

```
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

class Replacer
{
    const std::string token_;
    const int start_;
    int current_;

public:
    explicit Replacer(const std::string & token, int start)
        : token_(token), start_(start), current_(start)
    {
    }

    std::string replace(const std::string & str)
    {
        const std::size_t pos = str.find(token_);
        if (pos == std::string::npos)
            return str;

        std::string ret(str);
        std::ostringstream oss;
        oss << current_;
        ret.replace(pos, token_.size(), oss.str());

        --current_;
        if (current_ == 0)
            current_ = start_;

        return ret;
    }
};
```

And then you can use it like:

```
std::string examples[] = {
    "",
    "nothing",
    "some number #N",
    "nothing",
    "some other #N number",
    "nothing",
    "#N another test",
    "nothing",
};

Replacer replacer("#N", 18);
for (int i = 0; i < 8; ++i)
    std::cout << replacer.replace(examples[i]) << '\n';
```